# Command failed with exit code 1

Tags: reactjs, react-native, microsoft-metro

I ran the project on React-native with the npm start command and waited to build it to a device such as an emulator or usb device. But I get the error as shown below, please help me, thank you

I want to be able to build on a virtual device or connect the phone via USB after running

[image error detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdc0Y.png)

Comment: I recommend that you consider using Expo.

Answer (score 0):

1. What is your react native version? Make sure you follow instruction from react-native document to config files in /android/gradle
2. Have you installed Android Studio Code and ARM properly, run `react-native doctor` to see what is missing. Run `adb devices` and make sure your simulator/devices that are connected through USB appear here.